# Rails backend: Devise + Cancan + Helios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I've been developing a mobile app that needs to sync with a remote backend. Recently it has been released [Helios.io](http://helios.io), an open-source mobile backend framework developed by [Mattt Thompson](https://github.com/mattt). I want to use it has a gem into my Rails app, syncing it with my Core Data. I've some doubts regards its integration:

- Does it provide user management? Should I use something like Devise instead?
- Does it provide restrict resources? Should I use Cancan instead?
- Does it generate models and controllers based on the Core Data file with whom it has supposed to be synced with? Can I modify these files with custom codes or they are likely to be overwritten by Helios (e.g. when I change the Core Data)?

Comment: When you say "Does it provide user management?", what is "it"?  Devise?  Yes.  Cancan?  No.  Helios?  No idea. :)

Comment: I was talking about Helios, my Rails app already uses Devise for authentication and I was wondering if Helios can be easily integrated with Devise.